# Can't add data to firestore, no errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add data to the firebase database: firestore.

The code below, mostly taken from the docs doesn't write anything into the database, although reading data works without issue.

```
<script>
            
            var firebaseConfig = {
                apiKey: "...",
                authDomain: "...",
                databaseURL: "...",
                projectId: "...",
                storageBucket: "...",
                messagingSenderId: "...",
                appId: "...",
                measurementId: "..."
            };


            let fb = document.createElement('script');
            fb.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js";
            fb.onload = function(){
                
            let gA = document.createElement('script');
            gA.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js";
            gA.onload = function(){
                
                firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
                firebase.analytics();

                let auth = document.createElement('script');
                auth.src= "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js";
                auth.onload = function(){

                    let fs = document.createElement('script');
                    fs.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js";
                    fs.onload = function(){

                        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                            if (user) {
                                
                                var uid = user.uid;

                                var db = firebase.firestore();

                                db.collection("cities").add({
                                    name: "some_ad_id",
                                    coordinations: "41,41",
                                    user_id: uid,
                                })
                                .then((docRef) => {
                                    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                                });


                                var cities = db.collection("cities").doc('B3O4OwYq4RLXHSQeOTQg');

                                cities.get().then((doc) => {
                                    if (doc.exists) {
                                        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                                    } else {
                                        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                                        console.log("No such document!");
                                    }
                                }).catch((error) => {
                                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                                });

                                

                            } else {
                                // User is signed out
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    document.body.appendChild(fs);
                    
                    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
                    .then(() => {
                        // Signed in..
                        console.log('signed in');
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        console.log('not signed in');
                        // ...
                    });
                };
                document.body.appendChild(auth);
                
            };
            document.body.appendChild(gA);
            
            };

            document.body.appendChild(fb);
        </script>
```

If I change the library firebase-app.js to firebase.js, everything works (reading & writing), but of course I get a warning that this I'm using the development version of the library, here is the warning I get:

*It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.
For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js*

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

I tried the following, none of them worked:

- To embed the libraries writing HTML directly
- **await** for every initialization of firebase or a firebase product

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, I moved the initialization of firestore outside of the `onAuthStateChanged` method, I'm talking about this line:

`var db = firebase.firestore();`

I am not sure why that is, I used **await** to make sure that the `firestore()` method was finished but that didn't do it